# Create a PySimpleGUI holding a list

Tags: pysimplegui

I am creating a GUI with some lists of values.  Each row may have a different color and rows may be added or deleted.

Conceptually, I want to do something like this:

`layout = [ [sg.T('Above the data stuff')], sg.ListThing(key='-data-', [[]]) ]`

so that I can:

`window['-data-'].update(values=[ [sg.T(v, color=c)] for (v,c) in my_data ])`

Is there a simple way or does this have to be a Frame?

Answer (score 2):

There's no method provided in PySimpleGUI. Some methods can be implemented by tkinter code.

Here, try to implement some methods of `list` to `sg.Listbox`, also configure colors of item.

```py
from random import randint
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class Listbox(sg.Listbox):

    def append(self, item):
        self.Widget.insert(sg.tk.END, item)
        self.Values = list(self.Widget.get(0, sg.tk.END))

    def extend(self, items):
        self.Widget.insert(sg.tk.END, *items)
        self.Values = list(self.Widget.get(0, sg.tk.END))

    def insert(self, index, *item):
        self.Widget.insert(index, *item)
        self.Values = list(self.Widget.get(0, sg.tk.END))

    def remove(self, value):
        index = self.index(value)
        if index is not None:
            self.Widget.delete(index)
            self.Values = list(self.Widget.get(0, sg.tk.END))

    def pop(self, i=sg.tk.END):
        widget = self.Widget
        last = widget.index(sg.tk.END)
        if isinstance(i, int) and (i>=last or i<0):
            i = sg.tk.END
        item = widget.get(i)
        widget.delete(i)
        self.Values = list(self.Widget.get(0, sg.tk.END))
        return item

    def clear(self):
        self.Widget.delete(0, sg.tk.END)
        self.Values = list(self.Widget.get(0, sg.tk.END))

    def index(self, value, start=0, end=sg.tk.END):
        widget = self.Widget
        last = widget.index(sg.tk.END)
        while start < last:
            if widget.get(start) == value:
                return start
            start += 1
        return None

    def sort(self, key=None, reverse=False):
        lst = list(self.Widget.get(0, sg.tk.END))
        lst.sort(key=key, reverse=reverse)
        self.clear()
        self.insert(0, *lst)
        self.Values = list(self.Widget.get(0, sg.tk.END))

    def reverse(self):
        lst = list(self.Widget.get(0, sg.tk.END))
        lst.sort(reverse=True)
        self.clear()
        self.insert(0, *lst)
        self.Values = list(self.Widget.get(0, sg.tk.END))

    def item(self, i, value=None, bg=None, fg=None, bg_selected=None, fg_selected=None):
        widget = self.Widget
        last = widget.index(sg.tk.END)
        if i >= last:
            return
        if value is not None:
            widget.delete(i)
            widget.insert(i, value)
        widget.itemconfig(i, background=bg, foreground=fg, selectbackground=bg_selected, selectforeground=fg_selected)
        self.Values = list(self.Widget.get(0, sg.tk.END))

lst = [randint(0, 99) for i in range(10)]

layout = [[Listbox(lst, size=(10, 10), no_scrollbar=True, key='LISTBOX')]]

window = sg.Window('Listbox', layout, finalize=True)
listbox = window['LISTBOX']

settings = [
    (3, 'Red',   'red',   'white'),
    (4, 'Green', 'green', 'white'),
    (5, 'Blue',  'blue',  'white'),
]

for i, v, bg, fg in settings:
    listbox.item(i, value=v, bg=bg, fg=fg)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    print(event, values)
window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the write-up.   It handles a specific question, though I cannot do the thing I was hoping.   I'm looking for some sort of Element that takes a layout, or even just a list, that allows adding attributes like a key.    I think its a fundamental limitationof PySimpleGUI but the documentation is a bit lax.